# Use `shiny.fluent::Stack()` to contain UI element from other js libraries

Tags: r, fluent, shinyapps

See, I'm trying to make my shiny app within the `shiny.fluent` UI frame. Here's the problem:

### demo app

Demo app works fine as below:

```
library(shiny.react)
library(shiny.fluent)
library(esquisse)

ui <- shiny.fluent::fluentPage(
  tags$h2("Demo dragulaInput"),
  tags$br(),
  esquisse::dragulaInput(
    inputId = "dad",
    sourceLabel = "Source",
    targetsLabels = c("Target 1", "Target 2"),
    choices = names(iris),
    width = "400px"
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "result")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$result <- renderPrint(str(input$dad))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And I can drag & drop element as intended.

[image: demo app works fine]

### Problem

But when I try to wrap `esquisse::dragulaInput()` inside `shiny.fluent::Stack()`, the whole stack card just doesn't appear. (As for comparison, the `verbatimTextOutput()` is correctly rendered, resulting in a card with `NULL` output)

```
library(shiny.react)
library(shiny.fluent)
library(esquisse)

ui <- shiny.fluent::fluentPage(
  tags$h2("Demo dragulaInput"),
  tags$br(),
  shiny.fluent::Stack(
    shiny.fluent::Text("Dargula input", class = "xLarge"),
    esquisse::dragulaInput(
      inputId = "dad",
      sourceLabel = "Source",
      targetsLabels = c("Target 1", "Target 2"),
      choices = names(iris),
      width = "400px"
    )
  ),
  shiny.fluent::Stack(
    class = "ms-depth-8",
    tokens = list(padding = 20, childrenGap = 10),
    shiny.fluent::Text("Result", class = "xLarge"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "result")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$result <- renderPrint(str(input$dad))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

### My guessing

My guessing is problem happens in `shiny.react::reactElement()`, which is the foundation function of `shiny.fluent::Stack()`. I think there may be some kind of measures to "import" JS libraries like `dragula` into react to make a proper react element (since there is a `deps` argument in `shiny.react::reactElement()`, which takes a `htmltools::html_dependency` object as input). But I know nothing about front-end engineering stuff, so can anyone help me out here?